# How to implement a refresh token process with JWT for Android apps

Tags: android, android-asynctask, oauth-2.0, android-volley, jwt

I'm working on a Oauth2 Token system to access my REST API for my Android app. I'm having some problems with the token refreshment part on the client side.

Here is the flow : My app makes a request (with an access Token in parameter) to the server thanks some asynctask ( `PostCommentAsyncTask()`, `AddFriendAsyncTask()` etc...), so if the accessToken is valid it's ok, but if it has expired I call another `AsyncTask`  (`GetRefreshTokenAsyncTask()`) from the `onPostExecute()` method  of the precedent `AsyncTask` to get new accessToken. Here is the tricky part for me. When I get the new access Token I want to re-execute the initial AsyncTask request to the server. I can't figure out how to do it properly.

example1 :

request `PostCommentAsyncTask()` --> (acessToken expired) -->`GetRefreshTokenAsyncTask()`-->request `PostCommentAsyncTask()`--> (good token)--> Ok

**EDIT:**

I finally chose to use the `Volley` library ( no need to use Asynctask anymore ).
As I use `JSON Web Token` I can check the expire date wich is encoded in the payload of the token.

Here is the `isAccessTokenExpired()` method to check if the Access Token is not expired before making a request to the server :

```
public Boolean isAccessTokenExpired(String accessToken){

        String[] accessTokenPart = accessToken.split("\\.");
        String header =accessTokenPart[0];
        String payload =accessTokenPart[1];
        String signature =accessTokenPart[2];

        try {

            byte[] decodedPayload = Base64.decode(payload, Base64.DEFAULT);
            payload = new String(decodedPayload,"UTF-8");
        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(payload);
            int expireDate = obj.getInt("exp");
            Timestamp timestampExpireDate= new Timestamp( expireDate);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(time);

            return  timestamp.after(timestampExpireDate);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

And here is the  `refreshJsonWebToken()` method to get a new pair of Access token/Refresh token from my OAUTH2 server:

```
public void refreshJsonWebToken(){


            SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            String refreshToken = settings.getString("refreshToken", null);

            final HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("grant_type","refresh_token");
            params.put("client_id","client");
            params.put("refresh_token",refreshToken);

            JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL_OAUTH2, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {

                            String newRefreshToken = response.getString("refresh_token");
                            SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                            editor.putString("accessToken", newAccessToken);
                            editor.putString("refreshToken", newRefreshToken);
                            editor.apply();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {


                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("grid", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    }
                }
            });

            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);


    }
```

And finnally the `getPost()` method where I use the precedent methods :

```
private void getPost(String latitude, String longitude) {

        SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String accessToken = settings.getString("accessToken", null);
        final HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("action", "getLocalPosts");
        params.put("latitude", latitude);
        params.put("longitude", longitude);

        if (isAccessTokenExpired(accessToken)){
            refreshJsonWebToken();
        }

        settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        accessToken = settings.getString("accessToken", null);
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL_APP+accessToken, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            //Some code ....
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);

    }
```

Comment: You could use the `get()` method of your second `AsyncTask` in `doInBackground()` method of your first `AsyncTask`. The `get()` method of `AsyncTask` is a blocking method which returns a result - it's completely useless to use it on the main/UI thread but if you call it from the first `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` method (which runs on its own thread) then you can simply carry on with the original task once the second `AsyncTask`'s `get()` method returns. Just an idea.

Comment: @Frédéric : What library you used on Server side for OAuth2 password grant ? I am using Node as backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `Handler` is better in this case because `Looper` has synchronous message queue which is convenient here. You create a `HandlerThread` and associate your `Handler` with it. Then you can call `postRunnable` on it  depending on your needs, e.g. you add `PostCommentRunnable`, if token has expired you add `GetRefreshTokenRunnable` and `PostCommentRunnable`, - they will be executed sequentially.

If you still want to go with `AsyncTasks`, can you check whether token has expired before launching `PostCommentAsyncTask`? I think that will a be better design. If you can't, then you can execute them one after another because they work on the same background thread by default, e.g.:

```
new PostCommentAsyncTask().execute();

class PostCommentAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
    //...
    onPostExecute() {
        if (tokenExpired) {
            new GetRefreshTokenAsyncTask().execute();
            new PostCommentAsyncTask().execute(); // this guy will wait till refresh token is executed.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer ! I can  check the token before launching a request indeed ( thanks JWT ). I'm new to android and I don't know much about Handler, I don't really know how Volley processes but there is a queue systeme as a Handler. I eddited my post with some work hope it could be improved or help anyone !

Comment: ok, thanks for updating your post. so, what's your question now? I think everything should be clear now